# Distribute a generic type over a union

Tags: typescript, generics, types, union

Is there a way in TS to "distribute" a generic type over a union?

```js
type Container<A> = { value: A };

type Containers<string | number> = Container<string> | Container<number>
```

(Assuming that we know from the context when to apply `Containers` vs `Container`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

surprisingly, type inference would do that for you:

```
type Container<T> = { value: T }

type Containers<T> = T extends infer A ? Container<A> : never;
```

the compiler is smart enough to disjoint all of them:

```
type C = Containers<string | number | {x: number} | {z: string} | boolean>
```

type `C` expands the following way:

```
type C = Container<string> | 
         Container<number> | 
         Container<false> | 
         Container<true> | 
         Container<{
           x: number;
         }> | 
         Container<{
           z: string;
         }>
```

[ts-playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2AQwJYIgJwDwBUB8UAvFAN5QBuyANgK4QBcUuUAvgFDuiSyIrpYAznkIkWEAB7AICACaCo6AGZYoAQSgB+XkjQYcawkwwUsAbk7doMYjv77hg4JnQBzKAB8oCWgFsARqpepBLGfoGYrJ5kAF5MTi4IrlFe-nBw1BDICPiW4NYAjLbwugKYjs5u0T4BWPhAA)

Comment: Awesome ! That's exactly what I was looking for, many thanks 

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample code I think you want to define a generic type that is constrained to a union of types. One of these should fit your bill.

```
type Container<T> = { value: T };
type ContainerA = Container<string | number>;
type ContainerB = Container<string> | Container<number>
type ContainerC<T extends string | number> = Container<T>;
```

Note also that [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is a syntax rule in JavaScript. Its usage in your question is confusing.

Comment: @leetwinski 's answer fits my needs better, but thanks ! You are right, I'll change it to "distribute"   Cheers