# Trying to create a hex color type - TS2590

Tags: typescript

Trying to create a simple hex colour that starts from #000000 to #ffffff. However, TypeScript keeps giving me TS2590 due to the length.

```
type hexDigit = '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e'| 'f';
type hexColor = `#${hexDigit}${hexDigit}${hexDigit}${hexDigit}${hexDigit}${hexDigit}`;
```

Comment: This is because when you use a template literal type, TypeScript actually has to generate a type that represents every possible string literal that could be represented by each union member: and that number is just too large: [TypeScript has a cap of 100,000 types in a union](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336). Instead, I'd recommend casting a hex color as `string` and perform manual validation instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Template Literal Types Typescript repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65336900/template-literal-types-typescript-repeat)

Comment: How exactly am I supposed to use manual validation?

Comment: That’ll be just a JS function that enforces your string matches the hex code, using regex for example. You can’t create a hex code type in TypeScript now.

Comment: I don't know how to make such thing though

Comment: It’s just a simple regex: `String.match(/^#[0-9a-f]{6}$/i)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm a bit late, but maybe you also never got a real answer.

**Short answer**: This question is a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68766792/how-to-create-standalone-type-for-a-hex-color-string).

**Longer answer**: I've been looking for a solution for this myself, and it seems that, at least for now, there is no real way to make such a type -- not without generating one that is absurdly complex and stupidly heavy to compute.

Like, for instance, at some point I tried looking into making regex validated types, and found [this Github issue on TypeScript's repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579) which completely derailed to the point some guy [implemented a Turing machine with the typing engine](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579#issuecomment-711442913).

I myself managed to crash my whole session by trying out stuff and TypeScript going crazy over what I was writing.

Anyway, your union would generate 16^6 (16777216) possible candidates, and is above TypeScript's 100,000 union members limit. Sadly this means you can't *just* constrain a string to have the shape of a hex colour code.

So, your best bet is to check for validity at runtime, and/or to generate the string through a function that uses generics and type inference in its parameters like in the post linked above.

As for checking it at runtime, seeing your last comment, don't fret. It's very easy ! A very simple regex validator can be written like so:

```
const isHexColourCode = (s: string) => !!s.match(/^#[a-f0-9]{3}([a-f0-9]{3})?$/i)

if (isHexColourCode('42')) console.log("Won't print anything")

if (isHexColourCode('#A24')) console.log('#A24 is valid')

if (isHexColourCode('#be1337')) console.log('be1337 is valid too')

if (isHexColourCode('#deadbeef')) console.log('Too many characters !')
```

`!!` inverts the truthiness of the return value from `s.match()` twice so that it is returned as `true` or `false`

- An array is a *truthy* value, so if a match has been found, `!![...]` -> true
- Else if `s.match()` returned `null`, which is *falsy*, the value will be converted to `false`.

The regex is quite simple:

- `^#` Start of the line followed by a `#`
- `[a-f0-9]{3}` Any character between `a` and `f` or `0` and `9` (inclusive) three times in a row
- `([a-f0-9]{3})?` Same pattern, but wrapped in parentheses to make a group that is facultative (with the `?` quantifier).
- `$` End of line
- `i` is a flag that makes your pattern ignore the case. Remove it if you want only lowercase characters, and change `a-f` to `A-F` for uppercase characters.

Hope this helps, have a great day~

Comment: thank you! this was the answer I was looking for!